# How to insert a particular image in a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have theme which shows some default theme in it.The themes name is Flow Hub.In first page and all of the other pages I have a default image there.But my requirement is to replace that default image in there,with the image which I am inserting with the Post.
It could be thumbnail or any of the size.
Please suggest how to do it and achieve this with an ease.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a whole lot of coherent information here. Do you just need to know how to use the visual editor?

Comment: @John...Question Edited,Please check now!

Answer (score 0):

how to insert an image into a post , YouTube tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c--FXmLJ59A